# Kbd shortcut to close application menu in Xfce desktop manager (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: shortcut-keys, xfce

I've modified my keyboard shortcut to open the popup application menu. That's dandy. The Esc key or a mouse click can "close" the popup application menu.

Is it possible to have the Super-L (aka Windows) key toggle the menu?

Answer (score 0):

I really like using Whisker Menu. You can install it by pasting the following in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin
```

Here is the command to add to set a keyboard shortcut to open and close the menu. Super L can also toggle this menu.

```
xfce4-popup-whiskermenu
```